# Loading a UITableViewCell subclass using a XIB file

Tags: iphone, ios5, uitableview

I am having trouble getting my `CustomTableViewCell`, a subclass of `UITableViewCell` to appear in my table view.

I am using a xib to represent that cell, but I am assuming that the code for the data source delegate doesn't change. I made sure to set an identical reuse identifier inside the table view cell XIB.

I isolated the problem to the fact that the datasource method that returns the table cell isn't working correctly, here it is:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    CustomTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    DataObject *foo = [self.dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[CustomTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    [[cell overview] setText:foo.overview];
    [[cell price] setText:foo.price];
    NSLog(@"cell initialized, description text is %@",cell.overview.text);

    return cell;
}
```

Not sure why this isn't working, but that last log statement always prints a (null) at the end, and yes I did verify that the `overview` property of the data object has a valid string in it. Same thing for `price`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195726/how-to-create-custom-tableviewcell-from-xib  Try here!!!  I think your answer is there!!!

Comment: Yes it works, but I got an exception thrown when I tried that method the first few times, see my comment on the accepted answer for how to avoid.

Comment: hey @AndrewLauerBarinov , so I'm in kind o f the same issue atm but I'm using storyboards instead. Was wondering about your comment on the accepted answer, I didn't seem to understand by "IBOutlet connections are made to the view NOT the file's owner" statement you said. Sorry I'm kinda new with ios so I'm still trying to learn the stuff I need to do in terms of connections and stuff. Can you please explain a little further? Thanks! Also posted something here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15175472/custom-uitableviewcell-will-not-display-label-texts

Comment: When you make connections in IB you usually do it in the File's Owner (which is typically a UIViewController or a subclass), in this case you want to make the connection to the view instead which can be found inside the box marked view controller scene (as of xcode 4.6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .h file, you write it.

```
IBOulet CustomTableViewCell *tableCell;
```

and connect to File's Owner in CustomTableViewCell's .xib file.

You modify this in `(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

```
if (cell == nil) 
 {
     [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
     cell = tableCell;
 }
```

I think it will be helpful to you.

Comment: One thing I'd like to add is make sure your IBOutlet connections are made to the view NOT the file's owner (you get a key value related exception if you do this)

Comment: Also getting this whenver I put a property on my viewcontroller.h ...Connection "" cannot have a prototype object as its destination.

Answer (score 4):

1) Make your Custom cell class separate

2) XIB : File Owner class change to NSObject

3) XIB : UITableViewCell change to MyTableViewCell

4) Where you want to add inside table view code  as

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyCell";

    MyTableViewCell *cell = (MyTableViewCell*) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        NSArray *arrayCellXib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyTableViewCell" 
                                                              owner:self 
                                                            options:nil];
        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            // first table cell
            cell = [arrayCellXib objectAtIndex:0]; // *
            ...... 
         }else {

            cell = [arrayCellXib objectAtIndex:1]; // *
         }
        ...
      }
   return cell;

}
```

Object at index 0,1 ... are index for which order you make MyTableViewCell in xib, if you want to have more than one custom cell. means in a MyTableViewCell class u make unlimited custom cell and use according to requirement.

Normally, just make ONE custom cell in the XIB and do exactly this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
    int thisRow = indexPath.row;
    NSString *exampleText = [yourData objectAtIndex:thisRow];

    static NSString *CellID = @"cu5";

    FancyCell *cell =
       (FancyCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellID];
    if (cell == nil)
        {
        NSArray *cellTeam =
          [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FancyCell"
             owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [cellTeam objectAtIndex:0];
        }

    [cell someFunction:exampleText];
    [cell.someLabel setText:exampleText];
    return cell;
    }
```

Hoping may help u :)

Comment: This is a truly useful answer, thank you so much. This is exactly how to do it with a CUSTOM XIB and a CUSTOM CLASS.  If you want to "JUST" use a custom xib (no need for a custom class), use the answer by Jamihash here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15378788/how-can-i-use-custom-uitableviewcell-and-uitableview-in-same-xib