# custom uitableviewcell will not display label texts

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

And the value of the labels are null as well.

I'm not really sure what's going on.

These are my classes/codes

```
@interface CustomEventCell : UITableViewCell{

}

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *participant1label;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *participant2label;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *status;

@end
```

Event model is

```
@interface Event : NSObject{
}
@property NSNumber *matchId;
@property NSString *participant1, *participant2,
-(id)init;
@end
```

this is the tableview that fills up the cell

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"EventCell";

    CustomEventCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[CustomEventCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // events is a NSMutableArray with Event instances
    Event *event = [events objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.participant1label.text = event.participant1;

    return cell;
   }
```

Here's my setup

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

I must be missing something as I have another uitableview and it populatees the custom without problems. I compared them and they're identical. I even tried going back to the regular label and it would fill that up but not this custom one.

EDIT:

Modified the wrong copied code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a simple little test app attempting to replicate what you want to see working. I have made it available [here](http://ericgorr.net/cocoadev/iOSTableViewCustomCellSB.zip) using Storyboards. If you cannot figure it out from this, then perhaps you can take the test app and modify it so that it replicates the bad behavior you are seeing.

My best guess as to what might be going on is that when you initialize your cell, it is not connected to a view in a xib.

Try setting a breakpoint at:

```
cell.participant1label.text = event.participant1;
```

and verify that cell.participant1label is not nil by doing:

```
NSLog( @"cell.participant1label: %@", cell.participant1label );
```

I had a small bug in which none of my custom labels were showing up and cell.participant1label was nil. The cause was that I had not set the Identifier for the custom table view cell to 'EventCell'. So, I might suggest rechecking that and making sure the identifier really does match between your code and the XIB.

Comment: Hi @ericgorr , thanks for updating the files, that's exactly how my files look like, the only difference is that I'm using it for ipad and that the uitableviewcontroller is a popover that is called.  Also, I already did that log that you're recommending days ago and it is showing as nil. I'm kinda curious as to how do connect it to a view? As when I just do a regular [cell textlabel setText:@""] then it would fill it up with text, but not when i specify the object uilable.

Comment: The reason why it works when you use textlabel is that a UITableViewCell will automatically create that ability for you. If the problem is not mismatched identifier names, I am not sure what it might be. I would need time again to rework my sample project for an iPad using a popover ... or you could do that and make the test project available which reproduces the problem.

Comment: hey @ericgorr , sorry it took a while. Here it is. https://github.com/gdubs/customtablecellerror  I'm surprised even after starting from scratch it would still have the same issue. Just means I'm really missing something.

Comment: Well, I have to admit, I am a bit stumped. I haven't played with storyboards much before this. I agree, we must be missing some obvious. As a test, I created my own UITableView subclass and changed the class of table view in the popovermenuviewcontroller. However, I still get back a UITableView. Also changed the tag value of the table view to 42, but when I asked for the tag, I got back 0. It appears the table view tied to the popovermenuviewcontroller is not the one we think it is. Why, I do not know at this point.

Comment: Ok, I think I know what it might be. In DetailAfterPushViewController, you have [[PopoverMenuViewController alloc] init]. However, what you are creating (likely) does not have anything to do with what you have defined in your storyboard. So, the answer that would solve your problem is how do you create your view controller based on the one you have defined in your storyboard.

Comment: hmm. intersting. But shouldn't it be connected to the one in the storyboard since I pointed it to the PopOverMenuViewController class? gah, this is confusing me.

Comment: No. Check out: http://brianflove.com/2012/12/10/how-to-create-an-ipad-popover-view/  (And, yes, as easy as storyboards are supposed to be, there is still a learning curve there.)

Comment: awesome!! I'll have a read at it and see if I can understand it. Lol! Thanks for the link! btw @ericgorr , skimming through it seems like it was written just for me!

Comment: hey @ericgorr, so Ive been trying to figure how this guy had a connection with popover like this http://uploads.brianflove.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/2012-12-07_17-54-33.png . I was able to do that by making two segues, 1 from the button and another one from the vc itself? Is that right? it seems kinda off. Also, the prepareForSegue part of his tutorial is a little confusing, since he didn't really say what codes are needed for the setFilterDelegate does that mean i dont need them? It keeps crashing on that part,and the ones after that. I'm such anoob.