# How can i use custom UITableViewCell and UITableView in same xib

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to use a custom UITableviewCell with UITableView in same xib without creating a UITableViewCell class?

As you can see bellow i set the identifier for UITableViewCell and used it like this:

[image: UITableView and UITableViewCell in same xib]

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  }

}
```

But Not Working?

Answer (score 3):

Add a UITableViewCell *customCell property to your view controller (for example, your file ShowUsers.h)...

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITableViewCell *customCell;
```

and connect it to the custom cell in your xib. Then use the following code in cellForRow (for example, your file ShowUsers.m) :

```
if (cell == nil) {
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NibName" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = self.customCell;
    self.customCell = nil;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but UITableViewCell and UItableView are in one xib

Comment: You could move the tableviewcell to a separate xib.

Comment: Note if you want a custom XIB **AND** a custom class, use the answer by GauravDS here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11025572/loading-a-uitableviewcell-subclass-using-a-xib-file

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do as following code

Under ViewDidLoad or ViewWillAppear

```
label1Array=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"A",@"B",nil];
label2Array=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"C",@"D",nil];
label3Array=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"E",@"F",nil];
```

UITableViewDelegate

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"aCell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
UILabel *label1=[[UILabel alloc]init];
label1.frame=CGRectMake(0,0,40,40);
label1.text=[label1Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
................
[cell.contentView addSubView: label1];

UILabel *label2=[[UILabel alloc]init];
label2.frame=CGRectMake(50,0,40,40);
label2.text=[label2Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[cell.contentView addSubView: label2];

UILabel *label3=[[UILabel alloc]init];
label3.frame=CGRectMake(100,0,40,40);
label3.text=[label3Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[cell.contentView addSubView: label3];
}
```

Hope this Helps !!!

Comment: Thanks for replay, but i want to use an visual UiTableCell and without creating class for it in xib, it's easy to do this in storyboard, but i dont know how to do that in xib file

Comment: @ArashZeinoddini actually this code is for xib only.. Can u brief your question i cant get what is ur issue.

Comment: You know, i wanna create a custom UITableViewCell,ok?, and the normal flow to do this is to make a UITableViewCell with its class such as this tutorial :http://www.altinkonline.nl/tutorials/xcode/uitableview/uitableviewcell/ ,ok?, but i really dont want to make custom UITableViewCell class (.h/.m), and just wanna make an UITableViewCell in same that i created the UITableView, ok, and of course i set an identifier for using this created UITableViewCell.

Answer (score 0):

See..You can do like this. Here you are adding two UITableViewCell in one TableView using XIB.

In Class.h file :-

Declare one mutable array for number of cells.

```
      {
         NSMutableArray * sectionRows;
      }

    @property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITableViewCell *addTvc1;
    @property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITableViewCell *addTvc2;
```

In Class.m :-

```
    @synthesize addTvc1, addTvc2;

    - (void)viewDidLoad
      {
        [super viewDidLoad];

         sectionRows = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

         [sectionRows addObject:[[NSMutableArray alloc] 
                        initWithObjects:addTvc1, nil]];

         [sectionRows addObject:[[NSMutableArray alloc] 
                        initWithObjects:addTvc2, nil]];

     }
```

In UITableViewDelegate Method -

Add This -

```
    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    {
       return [sectionRows count];
    }

   - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:       
                                                      (NSInteger)section
   { 
      return [[sectionRows objectAtIndex:section] count];
   }

   - (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:
                                                      (NSIndexPath  *)indexPath
  { 
      return [[sectionRows objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] 
                               objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  }
```

Along with code, In Class's XIB drop and drag two UITableViewCell which should be outside from the view and add those cells with Files Owner.
It will work perfectly. Here no need to create one separate custom UITableViewCell class.